# Как отфильтровать массив перебирающими методами массивов JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, foreach, filter

Как отфильтровать массив, чтобы в новом массиве остались только те объекты, у которых во вложенном массиве likes есть допустим число 12.

```
var arr=[
 {
  id:1,
  likes:['12','23','45','67'],
  logo:1.png
 },
 {
  id:2,
  likes:['23','12','45','67'],
  logo:2.png
 },
 { 
  id:3,
  likes:['45','67'],
  logo:3.png
 }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    likes: ['12', '23', '45', '67'],
    logo: '1.png'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    likes: ['23', '12', '45', '67'],
    logo: '2.png'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    likes: ['45', '67'],
    logo: '3.png'
  }
];

var arr12 = arr.filter(i => i.likes.includes('12'));
console.log(arr12);
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо за быстрый ответ.

Comment: @EvgeniiKantemirov Пожалуйста. Успехов!